# Create a sliding notification in Android using Java

Tags: android, notifications

PLEASE HOW I CAN create a sliding notification in Android using Java like this pic [IMAGE EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEGSc.png) that implements random quotes bubble notification when the user using an others apps

I DON'T KNOW HOW I CAN MAKE IT

Comment: that is not a notification it looks like a floating button on the home screen you will need  `draw over other apps` permission to show a view over the home screen and over other apps